# Jquery And Bootstrap.js - DIV would show but not hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap CSS and JS libraries in my site and the following code:

```
$(function(){
$("#nav-login-btn").click(function(){
    if($("#togglesection").not(":visible")) {
        $("#nav-login-btn").css({"background-color":"#fff", "color":"#222"});
        $("#togglesection").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#nav-login-btn").css({"background-color":"transparent", "color":"#fff"});
        $("#togglesection").hide();
    }
})
})
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    if (!$("#togglesection").is(e.target) && $("#togglesection").has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        $("#togglesection").hide();
        $("#nav-login-btn").css({"background-color":"transparent", "color":"#fff"});
    }
});
```

The div would show and `#nav-login-btn`'s css would change but then the else statement won't execute if I hit the button again. But **the bottom code does hide my div** if I click away. What is the problem?

**Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmzk9**

Comment: $("#togglesection").not(":visible") could be simplified to $("#togglesection:hidden") for a same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement:

```
$("#togglesection").not(":visible")
```

Returns a jQuery object, which is always "truthy".

You want this:

```
if (!$("#togglesection").is(":visible")) {
```

[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns a boolean "if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments".

**Edit** in response to your fiddle.. try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/XsLNJ/

The `mouseup` triggered, which hid the box, then the `click` triggered, which showed the box.

Comment: Simple , Straight forward. That's it.

Comment: Last time I used the bottom one for checkbox and the result was funky

Comment: @DanielCheung It appears to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ea844/. Can you post a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Jason_P wow just one line! I better do some research. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try `if(!$("#togglesection").is(":visible")) {`

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jHfY/) for more details...

In the console you'll notice that `console.log($("#togglesection").is(":visible"));` returns a boolean, whilst `console.log($("#togglesection").not(":visible"));` returns and actual object.

Comment: you mean I need to change the else statement?

Comment: Apologies, I've included more explanation in my post.

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify to this:

```
$(function(){
$("#nav-login-btn").on({
  click:function(){
    $("#togglesection").toggle();
    $("#nav-login-btn").classToggle("active");
  }
});
});
```

then CSS:

```
#nav-login-btn {background-color:transparent, color:#fff}
#nav-login-btn.active {background-color:#fff, color:#222}
```